# NetworkX: Circular plot with a node in the center

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, networkx

I have a simple network where there are multiple distinct 'sources' connected to one specific node. The sources have no edges between themselves.

I'm trying to plot a nice circular plot, where that specific node is dead in the center, and all the source nodes are neatly positioned in a circle around that center node, with the same distance (i.e. radius) from it. Distance itself is not defined, and should be relative to the figsize.

I manage to get the target node in the center, and manage to get the other nodes form a nice circle, but not both at the same time. That is:

[image]

or:

[image]

What I'm trying to do is get the red node in the center.

Here's the code used to create the graph and the plots:

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

n = 283
n_new = 41

df = pd.DataFrame({'source': range(1, n+1),
                   'target':[0]*n,
                   'new_user':[0]*(n-n_new) + [1]*n_new
})

G = nx.from_pandas_dataframe(df, source='source', target='target', create_using=nx.DiGraph())
```

First plot:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(16,16))

# Node colors
val_map = df.iloc[:,:2].set_index('source').to_dict()['new_user']
val_map[0] = 2
values = [val_map.get(node, 0.25) for node in G.nodes()]

pos = nx.circular_layout(G, scale=2)

node_sizes = [1000] + [200]*283

nx.draw(G, cmap=plt.get_cmap('jet'), node_color=values, font_size=18,
        alpha=0.4, node_size=node_sizes, arrows=True,
               pos=pos)
```

Second plot:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(16,16))

# node colors
val_map = df.iloc[:,:2].set_index('source').to_dict()['new_user']
val_map[0] = 2
values = [val_map.get(node, 0.25) for node in G.nodes()]


# Nodes layout/ position
fixed_positions = {0:(0,0)}
fixed_nodes = fixed_positions.keys()
pos = nx.spring_layout(G,pos=fixed_positions, fixed = fixed_nodes, k=15)
# pos = nx.circular_layout(G, scale=2)

node_sizes = [1000] + [200]*283

nx.draw(G, cmap=plt.get_cmap('jet'), node_color=values, font_size=18,
        alpha=0.4, node_size=node_sizes, arrows=True,
               pos=pos)
```

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the function `nx.circular_layout` distributes the values on a circle of radius `scale` around the origin (0, 0):

> scale : float (default 1)
>       Scale factor for positions, i.e. radius of circle.

So all you need to do is position your source node, in this case is the node `0` at the origin:

```
pos[0] = np.array([0, 0])
```

And do your first plot with `pos = nx.circular_layout(G, scale=2)`

[image]

Or even better, first position your nodes around a circle without considering the source, and then adding the source:

```
pos = nx.circular_layout(list(range(1,284)), scale=2)
pos[0] = np.array([0, 0])
```

This will make a slight improvement to your drawing:

[image]

Comment: Whelp, don't I feel stupid. Thanks!  Any idea how you would make the second plot 'nicer' looking? By which I mean the nodes don't have to form a perfect circle/ellipse but let's say that for every node with edge of length x, there would be another node with an edge of same length, directly opposed to it (hence the edges would form a 180 degree angle around the center node).

Comment: Sure, you answered the question yourself. Take the equation of a circle at the origin `x^2 + y^2 = r^2` and distribute some source nodes on the circle. Then some others at `x^2 + y^2 = (r-c)^2` what `c` is you choose. You can even use  several circles. P.S if my original post answered your question, consider accepting it :)

Comment: Oh of course, just did (apologies). Is there a way to get it done without explicitly defining Cs? I like the appearance of randomness in radius length, just not the end result where the center node doesn't seem to be centered (if that makes sense :) ).

Comment: Also, that annoying sliver of whitespace on the right middle is annoying! :D You just know this is the kind of thing that will draw attention when I present, instead of the materialist things :)

Comment: I see. But I don't know right now how to improve that, sorry. What kind of version of networkx are you using? On the latest version you can add real arrows and even select the kind of arrow you want. Also, you could export your graph using one of the write formats in networkx and print a nice drawing in another software, e.g. Gephi [link](https://gephi.org/).

Comment: Thanks. Updated the version - worth mentioning that `from_pandas_dataframe` is no longer supported as is ([see here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_edgelist.html#networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_edgelist)). For posterity, [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.ArrowStyle.html?highlight=matplotlib%20patches%20arrowstyle)'s the documentation for arrow styles.